# Asus G531GL DisplayPort over USB-c not responding

Tags: displayport, usb-c, usb-3.1-type-c

I bought an Asus Rog G531GW-AL137T and two Dell U2415 external monitors. The laptop has an HDMI port that works fine, and a usb-c type port that should support DP as well (DP logo is actually right above the port).

But it doesn't. I bought a usb-c to DP cable. Nothing. No signal. Using a different laptop that has a thunderbolt port the same cable/monitor setup just works. Any information on how to correctly use the usb-c on this ***** machine?

Comment: What cable make did you use?  I have seen StarTech and PrimeCable adapters running over $50.

Comment: it's just a deltaco that cost 20 dollars

Comment: let me remind you that I did test it with another pc. worked fine

Comment: That may be the issue. It could be a compatibility problem with the current PC

Comment: explain to me how the same cable can get output through using a different pc. How is that possible?

Comment: Some hardware works with one PC and not another. Compatibility issues can work like that.

Comment: Well I'm not spending more cash untill I know that it should work. Not betting my money on guesses like this.

Comment: There are not normally drivers for adapters like this and we cannot fix compatibility issue like this in a forum

Comment: Then I guess I have to wait for someone with a similar machine to let me know either how to solve this issue or which cable/adapter actually worked.